# How to apply Newton’s method and find behavior of $g'(x)$ for $x$ near $\xi$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

**Question:** Let $f$ be twice differentiable on $[a,b]$, $f(a) < 0,$ $f(b) > 0,$ $f'(x) > \delta,$ and $0 \leq f''(x) \leq M \;\;\forall x \in [a,b]$.

Let $\xi$ be the unique point in $(a,b)$ at which $f(\xi) = 0$.

(i) Show that Newton’s method amounts to finding a fixed point of the function $g$ defined by

$g(x)=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$.

How does $g'(x)$ behave for $x$ near $\xi$ ?

**#** *I don't know how to proceed for this question. I need help in solving above 2 questions. Thank you.*

Comment: For (i), you need to prove that $f(x)=0$ if and only if $g(x)=x$...

Comment: "$f'(x)>\delta$". What is $\delta$ ?